# How to install KVM on CentOS 6

Tags: linux, centos, kvm

I can't install kvm on CentOS.

I got these errors:

```
[root@localhost etc]# yum groupinstall kvm -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: ftp.tlk-l.net
* epel: ftp.tlk-l.net
* extras: ftp.tlk-l.net
* rpmforge: ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de
* updates: ftp.tlk-l.net
Setting up Group Process
Checking for new repos for mirrors
epel/group_gz | 201 kB 00:00
Warning: Group kvm does not exist.
```

No packages in any requested group available to install or update

I also tried

```
[root@localhost etc]# yum install kvm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: ftp.tlk-l.net
* epel: ftp.tlk-l.net
* extras: ftp.tlk-l.net
* rpmforge: ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de
* updates: ftp.tlk-l.net
Setting up Install Process
No package kvm available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Is there a kvm package for CentOS?

Comment: `yum search kvm`

Answer (score 9):

Install the `Virtualization` groups:

```
yum groupinstall Virtualization "Virtualization Client" \
    "Virtualization Platform" "Virtualization Tools"
```

That will get you the `qemu-kvm`, `qemu-kvm-tools`, `libvirt`, `python-virtinst`, and `virt-manager` packages, and a bunch of others. Pretty much everything you need to get VM's up and running under KVM.