# Installing KVM on CentOS 6.4 without GUI (yet)

Tags: centos, kde, virtualization, kvm, x-server

I've installed CentOS 6.4 from the 'minimal' iso, so it doesn't come with a GUI.  Will [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18802/how-to-install-kvm-on-centos-6)'s answer allow me to install KVM, or do I need to install KDE or X-server or something first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can install all these package groups, even without having a GUI.

- Virtualization
- Virtualization Client
- Virtualization Platform
- Virtualization Tools

#### virt-manager

Remember that you can `ssh` into the KVM host and remote display any GUIs such as `virt-manager` if needed.

Also with the `libvirtd` service running you can run `virt-manager` from other hosts and remotely connect to the headless KVM host and manage it too.

#### groupinstall

Just do the following to install them:

```
 $ sudo yum groupinstall 'Virtualization*'
```

Also you can get a list of all the package groups with this command, specifically the 'Virtualization' ones:

```
$ yum grouplist | grep 'Virt'
   Virtualization
   Virtualization Client
   Virtualization Platform
   Virtualization Tools
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was not aware that you could remote display over ssh without some kind of X-server forwarding.

Comment: I'm a bit confused though.  The Dell guide says, "`--graphics none`    This tells the installer not to launch a VNC window to access the VM's main console. Instead, it will use a text console on the VM's serial port. If you rather use an X window with graphics to install the 
OS on the VM, omit this parameter."  Would I use VNC over ssh to run the Windows installer, or X?  I don't have either installed, yet.

Comment: @Kev - I would run `virt-manager` on the KVM host and have it remote displayed to your Linux laptop/workstation. Just do this: `ssh <kvm server> virt-manager`. You should get the `virt-manager` application running remotely. Remember that X uses the client server kind of backwards, the remote system is the client, your laptop/workstation is the server.

Comment: if I only have a Windows workstation available?  (Normally ssh with PuTTY.)  Oh, I found this to try, will get back http://serverfault.com/questions/299462/windows-vnc-via-ssh-to-kvm-guest-connection-failed

Comment: @Kev - I'd use this, [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/).