# Connecting to KVM on a GUI-less CentOS 6.4 using MobaXterm

Tags: ssh, centos, vnc, kvm, x-server

I followed the directions at this question: [Installing KVM on CentOS 6.4 without GUI (yet)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82533/installing-kvm-on-centos-6-4-without-gui-yet/82537)

But I'm not sure which feature (there are many!) of MobaXterm I should use to connect to the KVM.  On the CentOS box I ran `sudo service libvirtd start` okay, but what does that mean now?  Is it running a VNC server listening on 5900?  Or an X server on some other port?  (I.e., I assume I'll need to modify `iptables` to be able to connect, but which port should I be opening?)  Also I'd like to leave SELinux enabled, so I assume I'll need to do something with `semanage` as well.

If it is running VNC server at this point, I'm sure I can fix iptables, and maybe figure out SELinux.  If it's running X, maybe I can too, but then in MobaXterm I'm not sure which service tool I'd use--I don't see one called 'X Server' unlike the one called 'VNC'.

Also, will I be able to connect successfully (even if there's nothing to see) if [I haven't yet managed to actually install a VM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82562/virt-install-complains-error-no-such-option-network-bridgebr0/82568)?

Comment: why not simply use `virt-install` without a UI?

Comment: @dyasny, because I'm trying to put Windows on the VM.

Comment: `service libvirtd start` means it starts daemon process named libvirt which is for managing your all qemu-kvm processes, virtual network like bridge and iptable rules, and volume storages. then you can manage your virtual machines via a series of `virsh` commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every VM, that is properly configured, qemu-kvm starts a VNC or spice listener. The port and security are defined in the libvirt VM definition file (`virsh edit VMNAME` will give you access to that)
Once the VM is running, you can access the VM console directly using a VNC or SPICE client, no need to jump through hoops with X redirection